# How do Glyphicons works? How can I make my own?

Tags: html, css, svg, adobe-illustrator, glyphicons

I have a series of AI/SVG images that I've prepared, so I can use them in an icon font library like Glyphicons.  I've been looking through different posts and such, but haven't found much helpful.

One recommendation was using GlyphAPP, but it's Mac only and I don't have access to Mac.  Another one was FontForge, which crashed several times on me.

So currently I'm lacking a good tool to create a font file from my SVGs.  But even from there, how does Glyphicon allow their icons to work through a simple `<span>` tag with a class?

I use it through Bootstrap3, and inspecting the resources leads me to this http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff. Which looks like a normal font file, **ABC.. abc.. 123..**

**What steps and tools do I need in order to go from AI or SVG files to using my icons like I would Glyphicons?**

I'm not opposed to paid tools, in fact if there's something directly in Adobe Creative Cloud that I'm somehow missing, I'd love for that to be the solution.

Comment: For the close vote the help center includes this **a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development**. And I haven't seen another SE site that it would fit in. Webmasters, for example, suggests development style questions to SO.

Comment: Yet again a great question, asked exactly as I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you create a webfont which contains the various vectorised graphics used on a site to cut the number of HTTP requests. Sometimes they are bundled into a font which actually contains common ASCII letters as well.

You can then place the glyphs using plain old CSS font directives often in combination with `::before` and `::after` psuedo attributes.

Dafont.com has pretty decent writeup of [available tools](http://www.dafont.com/soft.php).

Comment: I hope in future we actually get a web format to package SVGs and raster images so we don´t silly workarounds like this.

Comment: Given the font files (svg, tiff, woff) where do I write the CSS font directives? How do I tell bootstrap or my site to use them?

Comment: You place font directives in your stylesheets. You  "tell bootstrap to use them" by creating CSS rules and applying classes to your markup.